# Do I need to call delete on IDisposable object in C++/CLI

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, c++-cli

I had been under the impression that in a C++/CLI method if a class I was using implements IDisposable, the dispose is auto-magically called when the object goes out of scope. Recently I came across some code that looks like this:

```
void SomeClass::SomeMethod()
{
    DisposableObject^ myObject = nullptr;
    try
    {
         // Some code that creates a DisposableObject and assigns to myObject
    }
    finally
    {
        if (myObject != nullptr)
        {
            // this is instead of IDisposable.Dispose
            delete myObject;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is sort of two fold really. First, do I need to explicitly call `delete` on the object. Secondly, in pure C++ it is safe to call delete on a null object, does that behavior change in C++/CLI, just wondering because it seems like I don't really need the nullptr check around the delete call if the behavior is the `same` in C++/CLI (I understand behavior the same is a relative term since the delete on a managed object is doing different things than on an unmanaged object).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You never strictly *need* to dispose anything in .NET (unless the class is implemented incorrectly, e.g. lacks a finalizer when one is warranted), but you absolutely should whenever possible. Using stack semantics obviates the need to call `delete` directly when lazy initialization is not needed:

   ```
   void SomeClass::SomeMethod() {
       DisposableObject myObject;
       // ...
       // Some code that uses myObject
   } // myObject is disposed automatically upon going out of scope
   ```

   Using [`msclr::auto_handle<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/auto-handle-class) in combination with stack semantics obviates the need for a `try..finally` when lazy initialization *is* needed:

   ```
   void SomeClass::SomeMethod() {
       msclr::auto_handle<DisposableObject> myObject;
       // ...
       // Some code that creates a DisposableObject and assigns to myObject
       // ...
       // Some code that uses myObject
   } // myObject is disposed automatically upon going out of scope
   ```
2. Calling `delete` on a value of `nullptr` is completely safe, defined behavior, just as in C++ – no need for the `if`.

Comment: the key is that you have a handle, and presumably use new somewhere in your elided code, so you need a delete, while this answer uses stack semantics. You would expect the destructor to be used when it goes out of scope. The cool thing is mapping Dispose() to a destructor for classes written in C# or VB.